# No code coverage for .NET Projects when MSBuild SonarQube Runner is used

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage, msbuild-4.0, sonarqube5.1

We are using sonarqube 5.1.1 version and faced issues while analyzing .NET projects using sonar-runner.

As the recent update says, sonar-runner does not support .NET projects anymore, we have installed MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0 to analyze the same.

We are able to create dashboards for the .NET projects now but unit test cases and unit test coverage is missing.

Could you kindly help us here?

Please note that we have enterprise license and all the existing .NET projects in production environment use Visual studio 2010.

I have upgraded the dev instance to check the feasibility.

Comment: Kindly note that we are using Teamcity for building purpose.

Comment: Test Cases are not uploaded by the MsBuild runner, so that these are missing is correct. What tool are you using to generate code coverage? By default only the Visual Studio Test Runner (*.trx) will be detected, other coverage formats need further customization.

Comment: @jessehouwing can provide some information on the further customization? We have the same issue, with slight variations.

Comment: The Msbuild scripts will invoke the sonarrunner with the project configuration you supplied. You need to manually configure the non-Microsoft coverage processors.

Comment: @sripriyanka Can you share any references or bolgs to setup SonarQube for VS2010. I didn't find any references for VS2010.